# Label overrides others

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I´m using a form with 11 individual labels, which each one is responsible to a specific letter/symbol. It´s necessary to create a effect similar to decoding/decrypting a sentence.

The form inits as:   **XcT25vCh@#*&**

and after some character-change effects it ends with:  **Normal Text**

Everything is functioning perfectly, but when I reduce the space among the characters (to put them really in a narrow space), the subsequent character (label) overrides the previous one, make it hidden.

In other words, if I keep them in a fixed space (even being a justified font as Arial), everything is OK.  But if I try to reduce the horizontal space among them, the right label overrides the previous one.

All labels are marked as **TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND** and it has no positive effect.
I tried also to set Autosize ON and OFF, again, without any positive effect.

How can I simulate a decrypting string without have to keep all characters with a fixed (and large) horizontal space among them?

Note that the problem is not related to the label itself (the character width), but to the fact of each one is capping the previous one.

Thank you.

Comment: I count 12 characters.  Any reason why you just don't do this with one label?  Or just paint the string in a panel.

Comment: Yeah, don't do multiple labels for this. If you need to do some fancier display than you can do with a single label, you should consider writing a UserControl and overriding its OnPaint method.

Comment: The main reason to utilize 12 (or 15, anyway) different labels is because the effect is done through different Threads, allowing:  1) each character moves independent of other;   2) the initial encoded string is random;   3) Each character (or string in last mode) cannot appear "growing and shrinking" since I utilize (and I must to) justified character set (Arial) and an unjustified set (like Courier) is not a choice.

Comment: Thanks Erik but I don´t see how OnPaint event could handle the "invisible box" each character draw on screen, even in Transparent color. May I wrong?

Comment: You would have to measure the text and then paint it.  TextRenderer.MeasureText and TextRenderer.DrawText.  Different threads?  What are these threads doing?  Any interaction with the UI has to be done on the main thread.

Comment: Hi Lars!  No problem at all with Threads, since they Invoke the appropriated method. Each thread simulates the decoding process of each letter, independent in time (number of characters to be displayed per letter) and contents (the chars that will appear). Anyway, I don´t see TextRenderer calculation be effective to avoid the "transparent box" overlaying other labels. I believe this is a problem of Visual Studio in interpret and display TTF fonts. Don´t mind, I will try another visual effect - perhaps a MP4/WMV video. Thanks!